# Can I dynamically set the user and password in Zeppelin Hive interpreter?

Tags: hadoop, hive, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I just want to check if Hive interpreter in Zeppelin can dynamically set the user and password.

My case is like this.

- I have table1 in hive and I assigned full access to user1. For another user, let say user2, i have not assigned any access on table1. The access privilege is done in Apache Ranger.
- I would like to use Zeppelin to check if the access privilege sets in Ranger would work as expected.
- I know I can set it manually from the Interpreter Hive configuration but I dont want to open that configuration each time i need to test particular user.

I am looking for something like this in Zeppelin. I can set it on each section/window.

```
%hive <set user and password here>
select * from table1
```

Thanks in advance.